# How to make a table print out the columns that are the same into one row?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

What I want to do is what is in the shown in the table. I want to only get the Math subject and order the units from unit 1 (UI) to the last available unit in the database; after this, under each unit, to show the homework related to each unit. I have tried to save it into an array with mysql_fetch_array but it stores the row that involves one unit. I want all the units and only the units with their homework under them.
My database is at the end of this post.
hope someone can help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>


<body>


<form action="" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Subject:</td>
    <td>Math</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>UI</td>
    <td>UI</td>
    <td>UII</td>
    <td>UIII</td>
    <td>UII</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Home work</td>
    <td>Math work1</td>
    <td>Math work2</td>
    <td>Math work3</td>
    <td>Math work4</td>
    <td>Math work5</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

I only want the Subject Math and its units with the homework that each unit has under them.
my database is this:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.1.6
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Jul 25, 2014 at 05:52 AM
-- Server version: 5.6.16
-- PHP Version: 5.5.9

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `school`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `class`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `class` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `unit` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `homework` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `dueDate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `class`
--

INSERT INTO `class` (`id`, `subject`, `unit`, `homework`, `dueDate`) VALUES
(1, 'Math', 'UI', 'Math work1', '2014-04-04'),
(2, 'Math', 'UI', 'Math work2', '2014-05-12'),
(3, 'Science', 'UI', 'Science work1', '2014-04-09'),
(4, 'Home Economics', 'UII', 'Home economics work1', '2014-04-16'),
(5, 'Math', 'UII', 'Math work 3', '2014-05-12'),
(6, 'Math', 'UIII', 'Math work4', '2014-05-21'),
(7, 'Science', 'UII', 'Science work2', '2014-05-14'),
(8, 'Physics', 'UI', 'Physics work1', '2014-05-06'),
(9, 'Math', 'UIII', 'Math work5', '2014-07-16'),
(10, 'Math', 'UIV', 'Math work6', '2014-07-14');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class WHERE subject = 'Math'");`
That will select everything from the class table with the subject of Math, if that is like what you're looking for but you need more help echoing the data, I will respond with more info.

Comment: Do you need more info?

Comment: @user3799222 I shouldn't that should do whatever it is you're trying to do, but more info might help, what are you exactly trying to do with that data?

Comment: I'm trying to display it out on the screen. 
all the Math UI and its homework then if there is another Math to display that unit in the table with it's homework under it. If you run the code I provided it will show how it is that I want to be structured.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired query will be like this

```
mysql_query("SELECT subject,unit,homework from class where subject='Math' order by unit")
```